# What kind of spinlock to use in make_request?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a linux kernel module that provides a (virtual) block device (so no actual hardware IO is performed).

Currently I'm using spin_lock_irqsave / spin_unlock_irqrestore to handle locks.

There is only one function running in non-process context, and this is the make_request function of the block device.

Would it be safe to use spin_lock_bh / spin_unlock_bh to handle locks? I guess that simple spin_lock is insufficient, since make_request is not run by a process (is this correct?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little update: I used the irqsave / restore kind of locks, and on some systems, the irq handlers were starved, so I finally tried the _bh functions. It all looks pretty now. I still need some expert saying that things won't go terribly wrong this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your make_request function actually does run in process context.  The only caller of `q->make_request_fn` is the block layer's `generic_make_request()`, which assumes process context (eg look at its use of `current`).  And as another example, drivers/md/md.c has `md_make_request()` which explicitly sleeps on a waitqueue.

So you are completely safe using plain `spin_lock()`/`spin_unlock()` as long as all the rest of your code is process context too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll check on md.c and the block layer code as you suggested.

Comment: Hell, if all your code is process-context then you should be safe with `mutex_lock()` / `mutex_unlock()`

Comment: Well, you are right. I'm just stuck in a cognitive pit. :) I'll give it a shot. I thought about spin locks not just because the seemingly possible interrupt context, but because these locks are held for very short times. Thanks for the enlightening comment anyway.

Comment: Thank you again for your notes, you've helped me a lot.